# Publishing archives in local maven repository

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I'm trying to publish jar to a local maven ropsitory. I've written the following piece of gradle build script:

```
uploadArchives{
    repositories{
        mavenDeployer{
            repository(url: "C:/users/Admin/maven")
        }
    }
}
```

But I got an error:

> > Could not publish configuration 'archives'
> >     For artifact {:upload_archive:unspecified:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty .

What's worng? I did it as the section 8.7 of the **[documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#N10621)** said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't set `project.group`, which is required for publishing to a Maven repository. Check out the full samples in the `samples` dir of the `gradle-all` distribution. The user guide contains excerpts of these.

Answer (score 2):

Your build.gradle file is missing a group definition, this should look something like this

```
    group = 'net.joningi'

    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url: uri('../repo'))
            }
        }
    }
```